# In Google Analytics, how do I remove queries that start with a ? but keep the content before it

Tags: search, replace, google-analytics

I have an example here where my All Pages is showing /index.php?from=http://share-buttons.xyz/ as a page hit.

I want this to report only as /index.php

I applied a search and replace filter of this:
^[^?]+(\?.*)
and the replace field I left blank.

That however removes the entire entry so it's like it isn't tracked at all.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: ?..although maybe you should just delete the spam visit entirely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to go to your view settings. Enter "from" and any other parameter you want to exclude in the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" box (separated by commas). No need to set up filters.

Comment: I literally found that answer seconds before you posted this. Thanks!